# Stop Re-rendering a particular View in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, timer

How to stop, a particular view from re rendering when there is an state change ? I am using a Timer countdown component from [react-native-timer-countdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-timer-countdown). What happens is after expiry, i am setting an new state. So when there is an new state, it rerenders. So the timer starts from beginning.

The library itself suggest to use two separate component. But, i dont feel thats a good. Is there any way to stop the timer to restart once done ( even at state change ) ?

My Code :

```
<View>
    <TimerCountdown
      initialMilliseconds={100 * 60}
      onTick={(milliseconds) => console.log("tick", milliseconds)}
      onExpire={() => this.setState({ disabled: false })}
    />
</View>
```

OnExpire , there is an setstate which restarts the timer again. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

A good practice in React Native is to have a parent component, which is called sometimes **Smart Component** usually class-based component,

It's job is to ed
 - to fetch data and make any logical decisions.
 - render child components accordingly.

these child components some people call it **Dumb Component**, usually a presentational component or a funtional component, it's job from it's name to render some content **only a change to ony of it's props received**

So I suggest you encapsulate the JSX that you don't want to be affected by the change in your state in a functional component. That way it will not be rendered if the change in state has not been passed as a prop to it.

in the code below, if field2 in `state` has changed, `PresentationalComponent` will not rerendered

```
class ParentComponent {
  render() {
    const { field1, field2 } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        ...
        <PresentationalComponent prop1={field1} />
        ...
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve. I think you can a couple of options:

- use two components (I think it is a good idea)
- make them use `PureComponent` for `TimerCountdown` (or implement `shouldComponentUpdate`)
- write this countdown by yourself (I think you will find a way how to make it when you write it completely by yourself)

Comment: Any example for pure component ?

Comment: `class TimerCountdown extends React.PureComponent { ... }` or you can wrap their component to your PureComponent

Comment: The PureComponent provides shallow comparison between old state or props and new state or props and if they are identical, it does not render. But, it rerenders when there is a change in parent component

Comment: And you change no state and no props of `TimerCountdown`, right? So it won't be re-rendered

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with this package too.

I solved it by removing it and writing my own component.

refer to this answer of mine, I explained my work.

[timer count down re-rendering and leaking problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55276733/8898138)

It's working fine for me ,I hope it help you and solve your problem too.